# Can I combine two parallel branches that were merged as if the merge had been done by rebase?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a commit history like this:

```
*   8 [branch: master]
*   7
*   6 (merge commit)
|\
| * 5
| * 4
* | 3
|/
*   2
*   1
```

Can I combine these into the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, acting as if the merge in 6 had happened by rebase, and resolve any conflicts manually?

Note that the branch commit 6 merged no longer exists.

Comment: "the branch commit 6 merged no longer exists" is meaningless with that graph. Recorded merges preserve the history they merged, that's how it works.

Comment: I was intending to communicate that the branch tag no longer exists, meaning it is not possible to switch to it without detaching the HEAD

Comment: Okay, I can see that now, syntactically that makes more sense but it's irrelevant. Labels don't matter. Commits matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing content or ancestry or metadata (stored alongside the commit message, say `git cat-file -p HEAD` to see the exact complete content of a commit, i.e. all its metadata) means changing ids.

You can produce a history that looks the way you want, but the new commits you're calling 4,5,7,8 will have new ids.

```
git checkout :/3        # :/ is message-search syntax, check out the
                        # most recent commit with a "3" in its message
git cherry-pick :/4 :/5 :/7 :/8
```

You can use [any other way of referring to those commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

If everything went swimmingly well and your new (currently nameless) history is the one you wanted,

```
git checkout -B master
```

to re-hang the `master` branch label here.

As @LeGEC points out in comments, `git rebase` was built to automate linearizing-cherrypick tasks like this, you could also `git rebase :/2` (or `:/3`) to get the same effect, plus it'll identify already-cherrypicked commits and just skip them for you.

Comment: I would also suggest: `git rebase <sha of "3">`

Comment: @LeGEC sounds like a good idea to me, done.